# UIImagePickerController camera view overlay based on rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to notify users to take photos only in landscape mode.
I got idea to put some overlay on camera view and if iPhone is in portrait mode to put some label with text "Use landscape mode instead of portrait".

Is it posible? Do you have some advice how to make this posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Text (label) on your overlay form (with the note). In the UIImagePickerController delegate check for orientation using , UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape and unhide (hide) the text.

I prefer displaying the text through out (irrespective of orientation) to the user for better user experience.